# Hibernate: Saving null entity in many-to-one relationship

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749208/save-null-value-to-many-to-one-hibernate-relationship-error), but my case is a bit different with cascading defined.

---

On trying to save a Task with a non-empty SiteEntity - all works fine. However, when you try to save one with a null SiteEntity there is a null parameter exception (unsuprisingly) - and using a dummy SiteEntity ends in creating a new row in SITES table...

This is the relevant piece of code (irrelevant data omitted):

```
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "TASKS")
@Entity
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="SITEID", nullable = true)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @ForeignKey(name = "id")
    private SiteEntity site;

}

@javax.persistence.Table(name = "SITES")
@Entity
public class SiteEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

}
```

Question is, basically, how can I save a Task with null SiteEntity - with the result that a 0 will be written to TASKS table's SITEID column?

P.S. Removing the cascade entirely (to save it "as it is and deal with site later") didn't change the situation.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Are you mixing Hibernate and JPA annotations?

Comment: As far as I know having `0` in `SITEID` would violate referential integrity if you don't have row in `SITES` with `id=0`. Why you don't want to have `null` in `SITEID`. In `SITEID` you can only have `null` or reference to row in `SITES` table.

Comment: Kayaman: probably - we are hacking a non-Hibernate-friendly DB before overhauling the system in the next iteration. :) So far the hacks worked.

Comment: Ondrej: yeah, I thought so as well, but we can handle this, since it's part-Hibernate DB [specifically - tasks are Hibernate; sites are not]. There is no reason to avoid null in SITEID, we can live with that - however, will it work with the code presented above? Or do I need to change the annotations?

Comment: Ondrej: update - removing the "not null" null constraint from the table worked. Thank you, didn't think along that line.
If you want to post that as an answer, I'll approve it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going from [Ondrej Bozek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/668417/ondrej-bozek)'s idea - the issue was a "NOT NULL" constraint on SITEID. Removing it solved the issue.